# No network connection after killing openconnect process

Tags: openconnect

I use openconnect to connect to my VPN server, one strange thing I've noticed is that if I use `kill` or `pkill` command to kill a background running openconnect process then the whole Linux network will be unusable, I've to reboot the system to get it running again, but using Ctrl + C killing a foreground openconnect doesn't effect the network useability, I want to make a script to auto restart(kill and re-connect) openconnect at 12 AM every day, so I want to have the ability to terminate it with pkill command.

I wonder the difference between killing it with pkill and killing it with Ctrl + C and how to terminate the process properly in a shell script.

Thanks.

Log

```
root@vagrant:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=144 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 138.338/141.269/144.200/2.931 ms
root@vagrant:~# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1397 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo
 1398 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 1493 pts/0    00:00:00 openconnect
 1495 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
root@vagrant:~# pkill openconnect
root@vagrant:~# ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I should to use `$ kill -2 ID` to kill the openconnect process, `-2` option sends "Interrupt from keyboard", which did the trick for me.